# Guidance to migrate to Fusion Tables API v1.0

Tags: api, google-fusion-tables

With the impending deprecation of the Fusion Tables SQL API, I want to ensure my application continues to operate as expected.

I use the Google Visualization api to visualize and query the Fusion tables like this:

1. To visualize the map:

   ```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),    myOptions);  
   layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
       query: {
           select : 'Latitude',
           from : table
       }
   });

   layer.setMap(map);
   ```
2. To query the fusion tables:

   ```
   var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableid;
   query = encodeURIComponent(query);
   var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
       'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + query);
   ```

My question is, what URL endpoints do I have to change to ensure my application continues working?

I would really appreciate some guidance on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Only the Fusion Tables API changed, see the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide) for details.

1. To visualize the map you use FusionTablesLayer, there you don't have a API endpoint, just make sure to use the encrypted table id.
2. Here you use the Google Visualization API, which did not change. But if you use the Google Visualization API to get data (rather than to visualize data), you should consider to [use the Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) instead.